# cannot open an image file in python

Tags: python, image, file, ioerror

```
import Image


imageFile = "C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\images.jpg"
im1 = Image.open(imageFile)



Error: 
File "C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\im1.py", line 5, in <module>
    im1 = Image.open(imageFile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2025, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

help me, I have installed all the necessary packages PIL ,Pillow ,Opencv etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387069/open-images-python

also make sure the imagepath is correct

Comment: You could also try using raw image paths as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21060179/1349663

Comment: can you try from PIL import Image instead of image and let us know if any change occur

Comment: from PIL import Image works while import Image gives an error

Answer (score 1):

hey it's not for your file path problem...

it's for your missing JPEG support in your PIL
here is my solution explained here.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59718/python-imaging-library-pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available-how-to-fix

Go to [here](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) to download the lib **libjpeg** package.
or just

```
brew install libjpeg
```

[image]